# Confusion around typescript errors when typings seemingly exist

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm working on a `react-native` project that is utilising the package `react-native-firebase` as a solution to providing remote and local notifications.

All is well, if I do the following:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'

...
const messagingPermission = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
```

The above code runs fine and has no complaints to be made. However,

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'

...
const customNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
```

Complains with

```
[ts] Property 'Notification' does not exist on type '{ (): Notifications; 
nativeModuleExists: boolean }'
```

However if I follow through the typings (ctrl+click) then I can see the class `Notifications` there and typed up.

Am I missing a vital Typescript lesson here or gotcha that I have overlooked? I'm positive the package is typed correctly so what is going on here?

I can provide my `tsconfig.json` if you think it would be helpful.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "watch": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "artifacts",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "filesGlob": [
      "typings/index.d.ts",
      "app/**/*.ts",
      "app/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "types": [
      "react",
      "react-native",
      "jest"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "android",
      "ios",
      "build",
      "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Edit: Added tsconfig

Comment: The `tsconfig.json` maybe useful in this case. If you could provide that, that would be great...

Comment: Added `tsconfig.json` :)

Comment: @Aleski If either answer helped, can you please mark one as accepted? (or comment if you'd like clarification)

Comment: My bad, yeh it was sorted by Chris below (not in 4.0.2 but eventually in 4.0.4 after some troubleshooting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an oversight on our part - we missed the static types from the Typescript definition.  I've just pushed up a fix which will land as part of v4.0.2 later today: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/commit/590d69ce8985842e830c234e18d020efc98e76c8

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `notifications` as a function: `firebase.notifications().Notification()`

---

**Why?**

Looking at the error message:

```
[ts] Property 'Notification' does not exist on type '{ (): Notifications; 
nativeModuleExists: boolean }'
```

It means `firebase.notifications` is of type `{ (): Notifications; nativeModuleExists: boolean }`.

What does the property `(): Notifications` mean? In an interface, a property `()` with no name indicates that **the interface itself is callable/represents a function**, in this a function which returns a `Notifications` object. These [callable interfaces](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/callable.html) can also have other properties, such as `nativeModuleExists` here, because functions are first-class objects in JavaScript.

Anyway, the error message tells precisely what went wrong, but the syntax it uses to do so is a bit obscure--making what's essentially a typo seem like a way more complicated problem.